# Diff Infowindows for multiple polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, infowindow

Here is my code, in which there is a loop for polygons to create and 'click' event listener for them for which a infowindow will be display.

```
    var GoogleMap,polyInfoWindow,polygon,getPath,getInfo;
    function PolygonToMap()
    {
        GoogleMap = // map initialization   //;
        polyInfoWindow= // Infowindow initialization for polygons   //;

        //  for loop of number polygons top create
        {
            getPath=    //  get path for new polygon    // ;
            polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
                paths: getPath, 
                strokeColor: "#0071bc", 
                strokeOpacity: 1, 
                strokeWeight: 2, 
                fillColor: "#000000", 
                fillOpacity: 0.1, 
                map:GoogleMap 
            });

            getInfo=    // get new data for new polygon //  ;
            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,"click",function(event){
                polyInfoWindow.setContent(getInfo);
                polyInfoWindow.open(GoogleMap);
                polyInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
            });

        }
    }
```

Here polygons are fine generating, but on polygon click for all polygons the displaying infowindow data is same( infowindow with data of last polygon info data in the loop).
That means in the for loop for each polygon creation, in the event add listener infowindows data is overriding for all polygons infowindw.

So, what i need is for each polygon it to be display its data in the infowindow will 'onclick', i.e., diff data for each polygon infowindow.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to associate an infowindow with a polygon is with function closure.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_clickable_squares.html)